# Matplotlib's Figure and Axes explanation

Tags: matplotlib, figure, axes

I am really pretty new to matplotlib, though I know that it can be very powerful.
I've been reading number of tutorials and examples and it's a real hassle to understand how does matplotlib's Figure and Axes work. I am illustrating, what I am trying to understand, with the attached figure.[image]

I know how to create a figure instance of certain size in inches. However, what bothers me is how can I create subplots and then axes, within each subplot, with relative coordinates (bottom=0,left=0,top=1,right=1) as illustrated. 
So, for example I want to create a "parent" plot area (say (6in,10in)). Then, I want to create two subplot areas, each with size (3in,3in), with 1in space from the top, 2in space between the two vertical subplot areas and 1in from bottom. Then, 1in space on the left and 2in space on the write. In the same time, I would like to be able to get the coordinates of the subplot areas with respect to the main plot area.
Then, inside the first subplot area, I'd like to create 2 axis instances, with Axis 1, having coordinates with respect to Subplot Area1 (0.1,0.7,0.7,0.2) and Axes 2 (0.1,0.2,0.7,0.5). And then of course I'd like to be able to plot on these axes e.g., `ax1.plot()....`
If you could provide a sample code to achieve that, then I can study it.
Your help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: a `subplot` and an `Axes` object are really the same thing. There is not really a "subplot" as you describe it in matplotlib. You can just create your three `Axes` objects using `gridspec` without the need to put them in your "subplots"

Comment: Then, why does matplotlib have two separate clasess `Axes` and `subplot`, when they are the same thing?

Comment: `fig.add_subplot` returns an `Axes` instance. `subplot` is not a class, it is a function that returns an Axes.

Comment: Hi @tom, then what is the difference between `fig.add_subplot` and `fig.add_axes`?

Comment: Too much to write in a comment, so I've added an answer with some details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `subplot` and an `Axes` object are really the same thing. There is not really a "subplot" as you describe it in matplotlib. You can just create your three `Axes` objects using `gridspec` without the need to put them in your "subplots".

There are a few different ways to create `Axes` instances within your figure.

[`fig.add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) will create an `Axes` instance at the position given to it (you give it `[left,bottom,width,height]` in figure coordinates (i.e. `0,0` is bottom left, `1,1` is top right).

[`fig.add_subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) will also create an `Axes` instance. In this case, rather than giving it a rectangle to be created in, you give it the number of rows and columns of subplots you would like, and then the `plot_number`, where `plot_number` starts at 1, increments across rows first and has a maximum of `nrows * ncols`.

For example, to create the top-left Axes in a grid of 2 row and 2 columns, you could do the following:

```
fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
```

or the shorthand

```
fig.add_subplot(221)
```

There are some more customisable ways to create `Axes` as well, for example [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-and-subplotspec) and [`subplot2grid`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#basic-example-of-using-subplot2grid) which allow for easy creation of many subplots of different shapes and sizes.

Comment: @ tom, thank you so much. Your help has really made a difference, as I was not able to understand all that from the matplotlib documentation. I appreciate that!

Comment: @tom Suppose one has generated multiple axes that one would like to add to the figure instance. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @MPath I guess that would depend on how you created them, etc. Probably best to ask that in a new question rather than me try to explain in a comment to a different question